# How do we go about creating a "Stack Overflow Salary Calculator" for Aviation professions?

Tags: feature-request

Its cool that developers now have a [tool](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/09/19/much-developers-earn-find-stack-overflow-salary-calculator/) to figure out how much they are worth in the workplace. In there interest of intra-forum-sharing, can this forum use that calculator and tweak it to be useful for figuring out what flight instructors, aviation mechanics, various types of commercial pilots, etc, are making based on experience, location, education, etc?

Comment: The SO salary calculator doesn't take into account the largest part of the developers population which is working in India, China, and other low cost countries (hourly rates 15 to 20 times lower), a practice discreetly renamed "[global sourcing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-cost_country_sourcing)". I wonder if aviation salary tool could avoid this pitfall.

Comment: An ideal salary calculator would take location into consideration such that if you enter California vs Wyoming you would get to different results. Likewise, if you enter your location as Mumbai vs NY you would get different results.

Comment: I would tend to agree with @mins payment rates for any profession could vary so greatly especially when factoring in India and China.

Answer (score 7):

The SO salary calculator is only a gimmick to promote their jobs website; it doesn't actually work in most countries or for most developer skillsets. The input to it is based on SO's annual survey, so to make a similar product for aviation, we'd first need a similar survey. This site isn't popular enough among professional aviators (like SO is for developers) for such an investment to make any kind of financial sense for the company.

Comment: This is an excellent point. I wish this site was more geared to aviation professionals and aviation professional hopefuls. A tool such as a salary calculator (even if its somewhat of a gimmick) could attract more aviation professionals. However, thats a chicken/egg dilemma.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, Dan is right. The salary calculator makes sense for Stack Overflow because we have the data (annual developer survey), we have the audience (SO gets two orders of magnitude more unique visitors than Aviation), and we have something to sell (Stack Overflow Jobs/Talent).

The salary calculator took a lot more time to build than you might expect, and there's really no chance we're going to invest in an aviation calculator.

If someone in this community wants to build an aviation salary calculator, I'd recommend setting it up on your own. There are probably ways to build it without requiring a sophisticated backend, and something free like GitHub Pages might even work. Then, if the community thinks it's neat and wants to promote it, create a [community ad](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3186/community-promotion-ads-2017).

Comment: I suspect you are right. There are websites that purport to have salary calculators for aviation jobs, but I find them questionable, usually seem to be over inflated based on what I've seen personally. Getting an accurate survey would be the challenge.

Answer (score 3):

Before anything else, please note that we are not a forum. A forum is a place for discussion, this is a Q&A website, the working principle is a bit different.

Now, semantics aside, you are proposing something that, even if we wanted, we could not do. This is in the hand of the network administrators.

You could try to propose such a thing on [the main meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/), after having collected here enough support in such a tool, but personally I think that the chances of it happening are quite slim, this website is definitely not among the largest of the network, so I'm not sure that such an investment could be justified at this stage.

Comment: Point taken on not being a forum, I just don't know what else to call it. Perhaps venue?

Comment: @Devil07 I think that website, or community, depending on which aspect you want to highlight, should be fine.